# Augmenting the UITableViewCell creation from nib process

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uikit

When I do this:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MYTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[[self tableView] registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:kMYCellReuseIdentifier];
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to override the method by which the cell gets instantiated from the nib file. Ideally a way to do so in code, and not dynamically during runtime.

Comment: You can probably override it if you call super in the implementation, but whether that works, depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What's the method? `– initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
` doesn't get called when loading from a nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all object instantiated from a nib file, `initWithCoder:` is called, so you can
override that in your custom subclass.

Another possible point for customisation is `awakeFromNib`, which is called when
all outlet connections are established.

Comment: `awakeFromNib` is perfect for what I'm doing. Thanks!